# CasperJS not submitting $_POST array

Tags: casperjs, concrete5

I have a form which contains a hidden field;

```
<input name="qsID" type="hidden" value="1368113958" />
```

This is a hidden field added by Concrete5.

When submitting the form its like the hidden field does not exist, Concrete5 (PHP) cannot see the hidden field so presumably CasperJS is not sending the hidden field.

Why is this happening?

**Update**

Using `var_dump` I can see that the whole `$_POST` array is empty

**Update 2**

It seems that this single piece of code is the difference between the form being posted correctly and failing;

```
casper.waitForSelector("#Question33",
    function success() {
        this.test.assertExists("#Question33");
        this.click("#Question33");
    },
    function fail() {
        this.test.assertExists("#Question33");
});
```

This code also breaks the posting of form data

```
casper.waitForSelector("form#miniSurveyView576 input[name='Question34']",
    function success() {
        this.test.assertExists("form#miniSurveyView576 input[name='Question34']");
        this.click("form#miniSurveyView576 input[name='Question34']");
    },
    function fail() {
        this.test.assertExists("form#miniSurveyView576 input[name='Question34']");
});
```

Comment: Could you post your related casperJs code ?

Comment: @Micka I have added a update

Comment: How the hidden field is added by concrete5? Is it adde by javascript with a trigger?

Comment: Its in the source, its not added via JS. The issue has become bigger though, as a specific piece of CasperJs code breaks the form's ability to post any data.

Comment: You mean in your casper script? or in casper itself?

Comment: In my script, not CasperJs' core

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically had to scrap this code as it did not work at all.

What I ended up with was something like this

```
casper.test.begin('web site up', 4, function(test) {
    casper.start(url).then(function() {

        this.test.assert(
            this.getCurrentUrl() === url, 'url is the one expected'
        );

        this.test.assertHttpStatus(200, url + ' is up');

        functions.viewPortCapture(casper, viewports[0], "1001");

        test.assertExists(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='ABC']"));

        this.click(x("//a[normalize-space(text())='ABC']"));

        this.waitForUrl(/abc\/$/, function(){
          test.assertExists("input[type='submit']");
        });
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```